# What is the practical use of the Kadane's algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, image-processing

This algorithm is interesting, I know that it's being used in image processing ( and probably other scenarios ), but what I find strange is that this algorithm also operates on negative values, and negative values are virtually non existent in the imaging world where there are a lot of `unsigned int` to represent the values .

Could you offer a practical example that takes advantage of the Kadane algorithm ?

Comment: If you subtract two images you'll end up with negative values... I know this doesn't answer your question but it's a common image processing operation which involves negative numbers.

Comment: Negative values may be "virtually non existent" in image formats, but almost all image processing and analysis is performed with floating point representations and negative numbers are very common.

Comment: This actually is not a stackoverflow type question. Simple google search would give you answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can handle problems like:

- [Station Travel in Order](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=15320667)

  > Given a list of n gas station of form P(D,X) where D is the distance from this station to next station and X is the amount of petrol available at this station, identify the starting station from where you can complete journey to each station in order from 1.....N. You can only go in one direction i.e from P(i) to P(i+1). Suppose you need to find the max sum.
  >
  > **Kadane's algorithm (solution)**
  >
  > ***Initialize***: 
  >   max_so_far = 0 
  >   max_ending_here = 0
  >
  > ***Loop*** for each element of the array 
  >   (a) max_ending_here = max_ending_here + a[i] 
  >   (b) if(max_ending_here < 0) 
  >   max_ending_here = 0 
  >   (c) if(max_so_far < max_ending_here) 
  >   max_so_far = max_ending_here 
  >   return max_so_far
- [Hotels Along the Croatian Coast](http://www.spoj.com/problems/HOTELS/).

Answer (score 8):

One of the obvious application is business analysis where you need to find out the duration of time where the company experienced the maximum growth or also duration of time with minimum growth which helps company to find what they did good or bad during those periods to repeat or prevent them in future for benefit of company.

Answer (score 3):

I am quoting directly from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem),

> The problem was first posed by Ulf Grenander of Brown University in
>   1977, as a simplified model for maximum likelihood estimation of
>   patterns in digitized images. A linear time algorithm was found soon
>   afterwards by Jay Kadane of Carnegie-Mellon University (Bentley 1984).

if you don't already know what is maximum likelihood estimation, then here it [goes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood) for you.